# IIS website. Could not load file or assembly.

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iis, dns

I'm trying to run a second website on my windows server using IIS manager. I copied and renamed the source folder of my first website, which is running fine, and used is as the source folder of my second website. So what I want is two websites that are identical except for the domain name. Currently, I'm getting this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Access is denied --> check your access rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it into the same application pool (you can do that in iis)

Comment: If you have the apps in the same application pool they share the same access rights. If you have them in different pools you should manually add the rights to each app individually. I guess thats why it's named an application pool ^^

Comment: Right... But I made individual rights to each site folder, to each app pool, what other rights did I miss?